# How do I remove duplicated classes on the same element

Tags: jquery, duplicates, removeclass

How do I remove duplicated classes on the same element with JQuery?

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="foo foo">link</a>
```

I want just one class in this element, as shown below:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">link</a>
```

I've tried it but unsuccessfully. Thanks

Comment: what is the the problem if there are multiple entries

Comment: Because there is a bug with a plugin and i need to remove duplicated classes.

Comment: @T J, I'm sorry for that, I'm newbie in the stackoverflow. I choose  Mathias answer because it was more complete, with a loop, that what i need.

Comment: @DougLN the loop is totally unnecessary..! both the answers does the same thing, the accepted answer is way less efficient...

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. I looked quickly and didn't realize that. Sorry (y)

Comment: Actually I needed to iterate over multiple links without knowing the class names.

Comment: @DougLN that is actually a totally different question... check the update anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the existing classes using [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass) and add one back using [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass) as follows:

```js
$("a").removeClass("foo").addClass("foo");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="foo foo">link</a>
```

---

**Update** (*As per comments*)

You can extend the jQuery function namespace as shown below for a more general solution which iterates over a jquery object and eliminates *any* duplicate class names:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.removeDuplicateClass = function(className) {
    return this.removeClass(className).addClass(className);
  };
  $.fn.removeDuplicateClasses = function () {
    this.each(function (i, element) {
        var arr = [],
        classList = $(element).attr("class").split(" ");
        $.each(classList, function (i, item) {
            if (arr.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                arr.push(item);
              }
        });
        $(this).attr("class", arr.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

$("a").removeDuplicateClasses(); // or $("a").removeDuplicateClass("foo");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="foo foo">foo dup</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="bar foo bar">bar dup</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wrapped it, included your initial answer and self-returned for chain-ability.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all classes with the .attr() function:

```
var element = $('a');
var classes = element.attr('class');
```

Then you can split the classes:

```
var classArray = classes.split(' ');
```

After that you can loop through through these classes

```
var temp = Array();
classArray.forEach(function(c){
    // check if not exists in temp array
    if(temp.indexOf(c) < 0){
        // add to temp array
        temp.push(c);
    }
    else {
        // remove class (and add again to get it once)
        element.removeClass(c).addClass(c);
    }
});
```

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/fwkj1pLz/1/ for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check if the element contains the duplicate class you are looking for and then remove the unwanted and add back again. Link to [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/np0yLona/)

```
<a href="#" class="foo foo">link</a>

var elem = $('a');
alert(elem.attr('class'));

if (elem.hasClass('foo foo')){
    elem.removeClass("foo").addClass("foo");
    alert(elem.attr('class'));
}
```